# Replace JTextField with an Image?

Tags: java, image, swing, jpanel, jtextfield

I've been searching on way's to replace a JTextField with an Image & nothing comes up. Is it possible to add a jtextfield onto an image  or replace on with an image?

I'm using a JPanel & I am trying to put the JtextField inside the image below:
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several ways this might be achieved...

The simplest might be to use a `JLabel`, set it's layout manager to something `BorderLayout` and simply add the text field to it...

```
JTextField field = new JTextField();
field.setOpaque(false);
JLabel label = new JLabel();
label.setIcon(...);
label.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
label.add(field);
```

For example...

This will generate...

[image]

If you prefer the text field to be transparent, you could add `field.setBackground(new Color(0, 0, 0, 0));`, which generates...

[image]

And if you don't want the border, add `field.setBorder(null);`, which generates...

[image]

**Updated with another example...**

Or perhaps you'd prefer a self contained class...

[image]

This is a little tricky, because `paintComponent` not only paints the background, but the text, you need some way to insert the background under the text.  To this end, I don't actually call `super.paintComponent`, but instead, we cheat, and call `getUI().paint` directly.  This ensures that the text of the field is painted, but allows us to paint our own background before it...

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;

public class BackgroundTextField {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new BackgroundTextField();
    }

    public BackgroundTextField() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.add(new TextFieldBackground());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class TextFieldBackground extends JTextField {

        private BufferedImage img;

        public TextFieldBackground() {
            setColumns(10);
            setOpaque(false);
            setBorder(new EmptyBorder(2, 2, 2, 2));
            setBackground(new Color(0, 0, 0, 0));
            try {
                img = ImageIO.read(getClass().getResource("/y9yBe.jpg"));
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            return img == null ? super.getPreferredSize() : new Dimension(img.getWidth(), img.getHeight());
        }

        @Override
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g.create();
            g2d.drawImage(img, 0, 0, this);
            getUI().paint(g2d, this);
            g2d.dispose();
        }

    }

}
```

There are limitations to this, the field should never be bigger then the image, as the image is not repeated, but I'm sure you could use a `for-loop` to stitch a bunch of images together...

Comment: That didn't do what I was looking for. :/
I'm trying to be able to type data & not have the border of the JTextField. Just the flashing "|" thing.

Comment: So, you need to use the last three options, `setOpaque(false)`, `setBackground(new Color(0, 0, 0, 0))` and `setBorder(null)`, which I thought I filled out...