# Transparency for JTextField not working

Tags: java, swing, opacity, jtextfield

I'm working on a log in server & my `JTextFields` aren't transparent when I set Opaque to `false`.

My code:

```
//username  
    JTextField jUsername = new JTextField(10);  
    jUsername.setBounds(520, 284, 190, 25);  
    jUsername.setOpaque(false);  
    jUsername.setBorder(null);  
    getContentPane().add(jUsername);  

    //password  
    JTextField jPassword = new JTextField(15);  
    jPassword.setBounds(520, 374, 190, 25);  
    jPassword.setOpaque(false);  
    jPassword.setBorder(null); 
    //jPassword.setBackground(new Color(Color.TRANSLUCENT));
    getContentPane().add(jPassword);
```

An Image what is still happening:

[image]

Anyone ever seen this before or know how to fix it? I've looked around but no one had the same problem as I do, & the fixes for theirs didn't work for mine. ( I Know I'm not using `JPasswordField` for password, that's temporary )

Comment: Try setting the background color of the text fields to a transparent color as well, for example `jUsername.setBackground(new Color(0, 0, 0, 0))` as demonstrated in your [previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20296131/replace-jtextfield-with-an-image/20296166#20296166).  If you prefer a translucent background, use a different alpha value, for example `new Color(255, 255, 255, 128)` would be 50% transparent...

Comment: Put in answer form please so I can ^

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Basically, the UI delegate of the text field paints not only the text but also the field area (within the border) regardless of the opaque setting.

What you can do, is set the background color to a transparent value, something like `new Color(0, 0, 0, 0)` for example, which is fully transparent.

For example...

```
JTextField jUsername = new JTextField(10);  
jUsername.setBounds(520, 284, 190, 25);  
jUsername.setBackground(new Color(0, 0, 0, 0));
jUsername.setOpaque(false);  
jUsername.setBorder(null);  
getContentPane().add(jUsername);  

//password  
JTextField jPassword = new JTextField(15);  
jPassword.setBounds(520, 374, 190, 25);  
jPassword.setBackground(new Color(0, 0, 0, 0));
jPassword.setOpaque(false);  
jPassword.setBorder(null); 
//jPassword.setBackground(new Color(Color.TRANSLUCENT));
getContentPane().add(jPassword);
```

You can affect the transparency of a color by changing the last parameter, for example `new Color(255, 255, 255, 128)` would white, 50% transparent...

You may also wish to change the caret color, take a look at [`JTextComponent#setCaretColor`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/text/JTextComponent.html#setCaretColor%28java.awt.Color%29) for more details

Comment: `setColor(...)`?

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels I was young and foolish 

Comment: Used [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43815941/not-managing-to-make-jtextfield-background-transparent-in-netbeans)

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels Actually, looking at it, is an attempt to get around the ui delegate ignore the opacity state, but I'll have to do another test when I have time

Comment: Using `.setBackground(...)` instead of `.setColor(...)` this works great!

Answer (score 3):

no idea what you tried, for better help sooner post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/), short. runnable, compilable with setBackground instead of Image

[image]

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.text.*;

public class LabelImageText extends JPanel {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public LabelImageText() {
        JTextField jUsername = new JTextField(10);
        jUsername.setText("MyText");
        jUsername.setOpaque(false);
        //jUsername.setBorder(null);
        add(jUsername);
        JTextField jPassword = new JTextField(15);
        jPassword.setText("MyText");
        jPassword.setOpaque(false);
        //jPassword.setBorder(null);
        add(jPassword);
        setBackground(Color.RED);
    }

    private static void createAndShowUI() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("set Opaque");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.add(new LabelImageText());
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                createAndShowUI();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: This must have something to do with different looks and feels, as under the Mac OS, this doesn't work and I'm pretty sure under Windows L&F it doesn't either, haven't tried though ;)

Comment: interesting, no battery included:-), really don't remember any issue with, but there will be an issue with [non_transparent selection in DefaultHighlighter](http://stackoverflow.com/q/20311598/714968) ...

Comment: +1, @MadProgrammer `and I'm pretty sure under Windows L&F it doesn't either,` - non-opaque text fields work as expected on Windows using JDK7. That is you just use textField.setOpaque(false) and the parent component will show through. I'm surprised this doesn't work on the Mac LAF. Seems like a bit of a bug to me.

Comment: @camickr I might be an issue with the border implementation used by the mac os

Answer (score 0):

I tried with another option and it worked for me.

You can modify the property `Background` of the `textfield`. Select the option custom code in the Selection Box and paste `new Color(0, 0, 0, 0)`in the `txtField.setBackground` property.

Then just change the border property to `No border`. and finally uncheck the `opaque` checkbox.

[Here a capture of my netbeans interface](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZJfnD.png)