# Not managing to make jTextField background transparent in netbeans

Tags: java, swing, netbeans-8

Even after setting opacity to false and playing with every dang setting (the whole day) in the jTextField's properties.

I'm sure I managed to do it a few times before, could it be something with the jPanel behind it.

It's just a jFrame filled with a jPanel set to a blue background with a jTextField on it with a background set to white, (tried alpha transparent color (0,0,0,0) caused bugs in netbeans [I get this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sGkHL.png))

This seems completely ridiculous.
Could it be a setting in NetBeans?

Ok, here's the code..

```
 /*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package textboxpractice;

/**
 *
 * @author Ed
 */
public class TextBoxPractice extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    /**
     * Creates new form TextBoxPractice
     */
    public TextBoxPractice() {
        initComponents();
    }

    /**
     * This method is called from within the constructor to initialize the form.
     * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is always
     * regenerated by the Form Editor.
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
    private void initComponents() {

        jPanel1 = new javax.swing.JPanel();
        jTextField1 = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        jSeparator2 = new javax.swing.JSeparator();
        jLabel1 = new javax.swing.JLabel();

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setAlwaysOnTop(true);

        jPanel1.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(0, 51, 204));
        jPanel1.setPreferredSize(new java.awt.Dimension(646, 464));
        jPanel1.setLayout(new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteLayout());

        jTextField1.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(0, 0, 0));
        jTextField1.setForeground(new java.awt.Color(255, 255, 255));
        jTextField1.setBorder(null);
        jTextField1.setCaretColor(new java.awt.Color(255, 255, 255));
        jTextField1.setDoubleBuffered(true);
        jTextField1.setMinimumSize(new java.awt.Dimension(0, 0));
        jTextField1.setOpaque(true);
        jTextField1.setSelectionColor(new java.awt.Color(255, 255, 255));
        jTextField1.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jTextField1ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });
        jPanel1.add(jTextField1, new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteConstraints(80, 70, 70, -1));
        jPanel1.add(jSeparator2, new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteConstraints(80, 90, 70, 10));

        jLabel1.setText("jLabel1");
        jPanel1.add(jLabel1, new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteConstraints(290, 80, -1, -1));

        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
        getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addComponent(jPanel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 1000, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addGap(0, 0, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addComponent(jPanel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 1000, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addGap(0, 0, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );

        pack();
    }// </editor-fold>                        

    private void jTextField1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                            
        // TODO add your handling code here:
    }                                           

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
        //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
        /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
         * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
         */
        try {
            for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
                if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                    javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(TextBoxPractice.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(TextBoxPractice.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(TextBoxPractice.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(TextBoxPractice.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        //</editor-fold>

        /* Create and display the form */
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new TextBoxPractice().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel1;
    private javax.swing.JPanel jPanel1;
    private javax.swing.JSeparator jSeparator2;
    private javax.swing.JTextField jTextField1;
    // End of variables declaration                   
}
```

Comment: `jTextField1.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(0, 0, 0, 0));` -- you're missing the alpha component.

Comment: I tried that and when typing a letter into the box when running the program it would leave graphical lines behind it and I couldn't erase it.. Does NetBeans just hate manual editing? I was doing it through the "Customize code" option when right clicking the jTextField and put in that alpha stuff you mentioned

Comment: And get rid of the `jTextField1.setOpaque(true);`

Comment: Ok, now it suddenly decided to work.
I swear I did this twenty times before.
Maybe I just didn't do both at the same time.
Thanks for the help